# setting up select() and write_fds in C

Tags: c, sockets, select

I must be doing something wrong at setting up `select()` and `write_fds`. Currently, when I call `sendData()`, for the first time, it sends 117 bytes (all of it) from the buffer. Then immediately  it's called again even there's no  more data to send in the buffer and it keeps calling `sendData()` forever.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

```
int readData(int j){
    return recv(j, buf , nbytes , 0);
}   
int sendData(int j){
    unsigned v = fcntl(j, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(j, F_SETFL, v | O_NONBLOCK);

    return send(j, buf, nbytes, 0);
}   

fd_set master;   
fd_set read_fds; 
fd_set write_fds;   
int fdmax;       
...
FD_ZERO(&master);   
FD_SET(socket, &master);
fdmax = socket;

for(;;){
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    FD_ZERO(&write_fds);

    read_fds = master; 
    write_fds = master;
    if(select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, &write_fds, NULL, NULL) == -1){
        exit(4);
    }   
    for(i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++){
        if(FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)){
            if(i == socket){
                // handle new connections
                addrlen = sizeof remoteaddr;
                newfd = accept(socket, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addrlen);
                FD_SET(newfd, &master);
                if(newfd > fdmax) fdmax = newfd;
            }else{  
                // we got some data from a client
                readData(i); 
            }   
        } else if(FD_ISSET(i, &write_fds)){
            if(i != socket){
                // send data when notified
                sendData(i);
            }
        }    
    }   
}
```

Comment: Umm, stop calling code that you don't want called.

Comment: There's no point in calling `FD_ZERO` right before you overwrite the same fd set from `master`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: You asked `select` to wake up when you can write data. You could already write data so it woke up straight away. Then you didn't actually write any data, but just went back to asking it to wake up when you can write data... which you still can, so it woke up straight away, etc.

Comment: @immibis thanks, I understand now that part, but still not clear what is the best approach to handle this. Do you have an example how this should be done?

Comment: @PeteDarrow Depends what you're trying to do?

Comment: @immibis I'm trying to write data to the socket without blocking, if it couldn't write all data, retry again until the buffer is empty. I guess I'm not sure yet how others handle this scenario. I can't find a lot of examples out there about the use of write_fds, most of it is about read_fds.

Comment: @PeteDarrow *When you have stuff to write*, then put the FD in the writable set you pass to `select`, and check if it's still in the set when `select` returns, and if so, write stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking select to notify you when there is space in the network stack to send more data (that's what the write_fds are checking).  Since you've only written 117 bytes, there's plenty of space, so it returns immediately, telling you to write more data.

As you don't have more data to send, what you want to do is remove that file descriptor from the `write_fds` set.  You only want to add it to `write_fds` if the call to `send` returned a short write (unable to write all the data), or EWOULDBLOCK (assuming you have it set to non-blocking mode).

That brings up the major problem with your code -- you're calling send/recv without checking the return value, so you have no idea how much data was actually sent or received.

Comment: Thanks. I do keep track on the return value of `send/recv` as well as if it returns a `-1` and `EWOULDBLOCK`. 

Though, I'm not sure I understand the part you said I should remove the fd from `write_fds` and on a short write or `EWOULDBLOCK`. Do you mean doing a `if (sent <= 0) FD_SET (i, &master); else FD_CLR (i, &master);`?

Comment: @PeteDarrow: In the code above, `master` is the union of `read_fds` and `write_fds` -- in general you want to track and manage them separately.  So what you want is something more like `If (sent < tried _to_send) FD_SET(i, &master_write); else FD_CLR(i, &master_write);`

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are almost always writeable. You should only select on a socket for writeability if you have previously had an EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK from a `send()`, and you should cease doing so when the write has been retried and succeeded.